# ASP.NET Core 2.2 Razor Pages MVVM Query the AspNetUsers and AspNetRoles Tables

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

.NET Core 2.2, Razor Pages, MVVM

I have a model that includes a UserId foreign key relation to the AspNetUsers table Id primary key. How do I include the AspNetUser model in the query? I want to display the UserName associated with the Id.

I'm at a loss as to what to do, there is a lot involved.

I think it may have something to do with this.

```
UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager
```

Here is what I have so far.

**Models/MyView.cs**

```
namespace MyProject.Models
{
  public class MyView
  {
    [Key]
    public int MyViewId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(450)]
    [ForeignKey("User")] // PK AspNetUsers.Id
    public string UserID { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Column1 { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Column2 { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Column3 { get; set; }
  }

  public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
  {
  }
```

**Pages/MyViews/Index.cshtml.cs**

```
namespace MyProject.Pages.MyViews
{
  public class ViewAspNetUsersModel : PageModel
  {
    public ApplicationUser AspNetUser { get; set; }

    public IList<MyView> MyView { get; set; }
  }

  public async Task OnGetAsync()
  {
    MyView = await myviews
            .Include(s => s.AspNetUser).ToListAsync();
  }
}
```

**Pages/MyViews/Index.cshtml**

```
@page
@model MyProject.Pages.MyViews.Index

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AspNetUser.UserName)</th>
      <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MyView[0].Column1)</th>
      <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MyView[0].Column2)</th>
      <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MyView[0].Column3)</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model.MyView)
    {
      <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.AspNetUser.UserName)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Column1)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Column2)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Column3)</td>
      </tr>
    }
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Whats wrong are you facing?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a `public ApplicationUser AspNetUser { get; set; }` in page model since you want to show the `UserName` in the foreach loop.

Assume in ApplicationDbContext, you have

```
public DbSet<MyView> MyViews { get; set; }
```

Your PageModel:

```
public class IndexModel: PageModel
{       
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    public IndexModel(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    //public ApplicationUser AspNetUser { get; set; }

    public IList<MyView> MyView { get; set; }

    public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {
        MyView = await _context.MyViews
                .Include(s => s.User).ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

In view:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MyView[0].User.UserName)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MyView[0].Column1)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MyView[0].Column2)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MyView[0].Column3)</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model.MyView)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.User.UserName)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Column1)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Column2)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Column3)</td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

If you would like to get all Users, you could try

```
var users = await _context.Users.ToListAsync();
```

Comment: I see, so because _User_ is in the _.Include_ it does not need to be treated as a separate entity and does not need to be declared unless it’s being used separate from _MyViews_. I did get this to work, but there is a bit more code that needed to be added. As soon as I get it all sorted I will post it all so others can see what it took to get this to work. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There are several files that need to be modified to get this to work. Accessing the User data and the Role data are related so I am posting the answer to include both. Once you have this set up, you can add columns to AspNetUsers and AspNetRoles by adding them to ApplicationUser and ApplicationRole.

Using Visual Studio 2019

I created the project with .NET Core 2.1 so the homepage would have the slider, then I changed it to .NET Core 2.2.

```
Project > IdentityCore Properties > Target Framework
```

Update the dependencies

```
Tools > NuGet Package Mangager > Manage NuGet Packages for Solution
```

There are 8 files involved

- Modify or add the first 6 files
- Add the Pages/MyView folder
- Add Razor Page CRUD
- Modify Pages/MyViews/Index.cshtml

Here are the 8 files

---

**Startup.cs**

```
using IdentityCore.Models;

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            /*services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();*/
            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(options => options.Stores.MaxLengthForKeys = 128) // preserve string length of keys
               .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
               .AddDefaultUI()
               .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

**Data/ApplicationDbContext.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using IdentityCore.Models;

namespace IdentityCore.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, string>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
        public DbSet<MyView> MyViews { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Pages/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml**

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
@using IdentityCore.Models;

@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager
```

**Models/ApplicationUser.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace IdentityCore.Models
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public ApplicationUser() : base() { }

        public virtual ICollection<MyView> MyViews { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Models/ApplicationRole.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace IdentityCore.Models
{
    public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
    {
        public ApplicationRole() : base() { }
    }
}
```

**Models/MyView.cs**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace IdentityCore.Models
{
    public class MyView
    {
        [Key]
        public int MyViewId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(450)")] // match with primary key
        [ForeignKey("User")]                 // primary key AspNetUseres.Id
        public string UserId { get; set; }

        public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Column1 { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Column2 { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Column3 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Pages/MyViews/Index.cshtml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using IdentityCore.Data;
using IdentityCore.Models;

namespace IdentityCore.Pages.MyViews
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly IdentityCore.Data.ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public IndexModel(IdentityCore.Data.ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IList<MyView> MyView { get;set; }

        public async Task OnGetAsync()
        {
            MyView = await _context.MyViews
                .Include(m => m.User).ToListAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

**Pages/MyViews/Index.cshtml**

```
@page
@model IdentityCore.Pages.MyViews.IndexModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    <a asp-page="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MyView[0].User)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MyView[0].Column1)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MyView[0].Column2)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MyView[0].Column3)</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model.MyView) {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.User.UserName)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Column1)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Column2)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Column3)</td>
            <td>
                <a asp-page="./Edit" asp-route-id="@item.MyViewId">Edit</a> |
                <a asp-page="./Details" asp-route-id="@item.MyViewId">Details</a> |
                <a asp-page="./Delete" asp-route-id="@item.MyViewId">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
}
    </tbody>
</table>
```